# Nginx How to Rate Limit Total Request in a Day

Tags: nginx

I would like to rate limit the user to 10,000 total requests in a day/24 hour period.

However, I do not want to rate limit the user within a second or minute. For example, the user can make all 10K requests in one minute, or spread them out over an hour or the entire day. As soon as the user hits 10K requests, I want to reject all further requests until the next day.

Calculating 10,000 / (24 * 60) ~= 7 doesn't work:

```
limit_req_zone $http_username zone=per_day:10m rate=7r/m;
```

While this would limit the number of requests to approximately 10K per day, it also limits the number of requests to 7 per minute.

I instead want the user to be able to request a much larger number of requests per minute, so long as the total requests per day remains under 10K.

As far as I can tell, bursting will also not help in this situation.

Is it possible to do this in Nginx?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK with limit module it cannot be done but you can achieve it using LUA. It's one of default modules in openresty (enhanced version of nginx) and it has "limit" module which will do what you need. You can look [on their github page](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-limit-traffic/blob/master/README.md#installation)